# Cannot get MajorUpgrade to work with setup produced with different installer

Tags: installation, wix

I have a problem getting a wix installer to do a major upgrade when the previous versions installer was made by a different toolkit. I have my product defined like this:

```
    <Product Version="!(bind.FileVersion.baustatik.exe)" Id="*" 
Name="DIE Anwendungen"  
Language="0" 
Codepage="1252" 
Manufacturer="D.I.E. Software GmbH" 
UpgradeCode="6DCA3BAD-77E9-41AE-8F72-B92DE136C499">

<Package InstallerVersion="400"  
Compressed="yes" 
InstallScope="perMachine" 
InstallPrivileges="elevated" />

<MajorUpgrade  
AllowDowngrades="no" 
AllowSameVersionUpgrades="no"  
DowngradeErrorMessage="Es ist bereits eine neuere Version von [ProductName] installiert." />
```

..... other stuff

The above produces an msi. That msi is chained inside a bundle. The bundle is defined like this:

```
<Bundle Name="DIE Anwendungen" 
Version="!(bind.packageVersion.The32bitMsi)" 
Manufacturer="D.I.E. Software GmbH" 
UpgradeCode="6DCA3BAD-77E9-41AE-8F72-B92DE136C499"
HelpUrl="https://www.die.de/impressum" 
Copyright="Copyright D.I.E. Software GmbH" 
HelpTelephone="0800 343 2255"
UpdateUrl="https://www.die.de/downloads.aspx"
IconSourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)applications\xfalt\xfalt.loader\baustatik.ico"
AboutUrl="https://www.die.de">    

<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
        <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication 
         LogoFile="res/banner.png"
         ThemeFile ="res/ClassicTheme.xml"
         LocalizationFile="res/ClassicTheme.wxl"
         SuppressOptionsUI="yes" 
         LicenseUrl=""/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

I have verified that
- i'm using the same upgrade code
- i'm building a new product code (*) for every update
- I'm using the same language-id (language_neutral: 0)
- !(bind.FileVersion.baustatik.exe) produces the version info that i expect

When i build the setup like this, install, increase the version number, build and install (all using wix), the major upgrade takes place.

When i install the setup for a previous version (one that was build using 'advanced installer') - where the upgrade code was the same - and next install a newer version where the setup was build using wix, the major upgrade does *not* work. i.e.: No files or startmenu entries from the previous version are beeing removed and i end up with 2 entries in control panel.

Any suggestions what might be causing this ?

**(Edit)**

I did what Bogdan suggested. The full log, however, did not have any helpful information.

FindRelatenProducts:
MSI (c) (8C:88) [17:34:20:741]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
MSI (c) (8C:88) [17:34:20:741]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Aktion 17:34:20: FindRelatedProducts. Nach verwandten Anwendungen wird gesucht
Aktion gestartet um 17:34:20: FindRelatedProducts.
Aktion beendet um 17:34:20: FindRelatedProducts. Rückgabewert 1.

... and later:

MSI (s) (2C:04) [17:34:24:762]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
MSI (s) (2C:04) [17:34:24:762]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Aktion gestartet um 17:34:24: FindRelatedProducts.
MSI (s) (2C:04) [17:34:24:762]: Skipping FindRelatedProducts action: already done on client side

RemoveExistringProducts gives:

Aktion gestartet um 17:34:24: RemoveExistingProducts.
MSI (s) (2C:04) [17:34:24:841]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (2C:04) [17:34:24:841]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 22 
MSI (s) (2C:04) [17:34:24:841]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (2C:04) [17:34:24:841]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 23 
MSI (s) (2C:04) [17:34:24:841]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (2C:04) [17:34:24:841]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 16 
MSI (s) (2C:04) [17:34:24:841]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (2C:04) [17:34:24:841]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 21 
Aktion beendet um 17:34:24: RemoveExistingProducts. Rückgabewert 1.

Concerning perUser/perMachine:

In my (wix)package (see code) i have "InstallScope='perMachine'" and in the "AdvancedInstaller" i have "Installation Type: per machine only" - i assume this is the same thing.

Any other ideas?

**(EDIT 2)**

I have done as PhilDW suggested and opened the upgrade tables for the old and the new msi using orca. I did find the following.

Old msi:
[image]

New msi:
[image]

However, i do not know what to make of that. Given that information, does anybody know what i have to put in my wix code in order to upgrade the old msi ?

Answer (score 1):

The major upgrade could fail even if the upgradecode is the same, if the install type of the package is different (*per user or per machine - this happens a lot*) or if the install language is different (*which you already checked*).

You can install the new MSI and [create a verbose log](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-log.html) while you do this, then search the log for **RemoveExistingProducts** and **FindRelatedProducts**. Next to one of these standard actions you will find an explicit message about why the upgrade is skipped.

Comment: You can also define properties using two `<Upgrade Id="UpgradeGUID"><UpgradeVersion Maximum="x.x.x.x" Property="OLDINSTALLDETECTED1" ... OnlyDetect="yes" /></Upgrade>` with non-overlapping minimum and maximum versions to see which property gets detected during the upgrade. Basically Explicitly defining the Upgrade tags instead of using the MajorUpgrade wrapper of these tags that WiX implemented.

Comment: i did this. (In order to create the verbose log, i was using msiexec instead of the bootstrapper. maybe this is causing different results too ?).

However, the verbose log, concerning RemoveExistrigProducts, contains the following:

Aktion gestartet um 17:34:24: RemoveExistingProducts.
MSI (s) (2C:04) [17:34:24:841]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 22 
... etc.

FindRelatedProducts only says: Return-Value: 1 ... and, at a later point in the log:  Skipping FindRelatedProducts action: already done on client side

Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

Bogdan is on the right track. However the log would indicate if there was a related product installed, and it would show its ProductCode and say something about the other context, and those things are not in the log. That means you'll need to look directly at the Upgrade table in the MSI file to make sure that the version checking is correct in the minimum/maximum fields. There's nothing in the posted data I can see verifying the actual version of the older product and the versions that the Upgrade will search for. It also wouldn't hurt as a sanity check to see that you actually have an Upgrade table in your MSI. Docs here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372379(v=vs.85).aspx

You may as well check that the languages match with the older product, and that the Attributes don't have OnlyDetect set (unlikely, but being thorough).

It's also not clear to me that you have incremented ProductVersion in the first three fields, another requirement for a major upgrade.

There are some odd things that can cause issues. WiX forces uppercase Guids at build time, as required for ProductCode. I have come across issues when the original product was installed with lowercase ProductCode or UpgradeCode, and that was because it seems that some of the searches related to these are case-sensitive. Unlikely, however.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have solved it was setting the predefined `REINSTALL` and `REINSTALLMODE` properties manually like this...

```
<Product>

<!-- ... your code ... -->

<SetProperty Id="REINSTALL" Value="ALL" After="FindRelatedProducts">Installed AND REMOVE&lt;&gt;"ALL"</SetProperty>
<SetProperty Id="REINSTALLMODE" Value="omus" After="FindRelatedProducts">Installed AND REMOVE&lt;&gt;"ALL"</SetProperty>

<!-- ... your code ... -->

</Product>
```

... where `omus` refers to these codes:

> o  :  Reinstall if the file is missing or is an older version.
>   m  :  Rewrite all required registry entries from the Registry Table that go to the
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
>   or
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
>   registry hive.
>   u  :  Rewrite all required registry entries from the Registry Table that go to the
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER
>   or
>   HKEY_USERS
>   registry hive.
>   s  :  Reinstall all shortcuts and re-cache all icons overwriting any existing shortcuts and icons.

You can also use `e` or `a` instead of `o`:

> e  :  Reinstall if the file is missing, or is an equal or older version.
>   a  :  Force all files to be reinstalled, regardless of checksum or version.

(Taken from Microsofts development center [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371182(v=vs.85).aspx))

Comment: Thanks. However, i have a feeling it's not even finding the older installation...(at least the log, to me, looks like that)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: For some strange reasons, the Upgrade-Code that is listed in my version of the 'Advanced Installers' UI, is NOT the actual upgrade-code. Using orca revealed the one from the UI (which I was using) as well as a different one (which was not shown in the UI).

Changing the upgrade code in the wix source so it uses the "other" Upgrade-Code worked.

Note: I could not find Orca on microsoft.com. MSDN has several references to it, and it's supposed to be part of the Windows SDK, but it's not. I used an alternative download site which still had a copy.

Comment: Orca is a part of the SDK, but not installed by default. You need to search for "Orca.msi" in the installed resources of the SDK and then manually install it.

Comment: Regarding the second upgradecode, you or somebody else from your team that worked with the AI project probably added the second upgradecode in the list because they wanted to upgrade an application which had the code.